# Exception thrown: read access violation (Linked List)

Tags: c++, exception, linked-list

I'm making a singly Linked List called **Tracks**, why is it throwing exception when I try to make a `ptr` of type `Tracks` and assign `head` to it. It also gives same error when I assign `mbidd` value to `node->trackRef->mbid`

Test Case:

```
TEST(SoundCloudTesting, AlbumDatabase)
{
    string path = "Albums.csv";
    ad = Create_AD<int, string, float>(path); //function to be implemented

    int expected_albums[] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13 }; //expected abid(s)

    //Testing AD Data structure
    AD<int, string, float>* current = ad;
    for (int i = 0; i < 13; i++)
    {
        EXPECT_EQ(expected_albums[i], current->abid);

        current = current->next;
    }
    EXPECT_EQ(1, current->abid);
}
```

[Please check the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i6CfY.png)

Comment: Please post a [mcve], not just the class, but also a `main` that duplicates the error.

Comment: Where is your source code that uses this class? (Your input which caused the crash)

Comment: What's the definition of `MMD`?

Comment: Updated the code.

Answer (score 1):

The member variable `trackRef` is a pointer and was never initialized, but you dereferenced it here:

```
trackRef->mbid = 0;
```

I can't tell from your code where `trackRef` is meant to be created for each new `Tracks` or should be passed in to the constructor, but at the moment there is no code that sets it to anything before it is used.

Comment: It is still throwing exception when I assign `mbidd` value to `node->trackRef->mbid`

Comment: With your updated code you set `trackRef` to `nullptr` then try to dereference it `createList` - if you want to dereference a pointer it must point to valid memory.

Comment: But I want my linked list empty at first, how should I point it to a valid memory?

Comment: What is trackRef meant to be for? What does it hold? It seems to be another linked list of MMD objects, but why is it a linked list? What is in charge of this other linked list? Is there one MMD linked list per Tracks object, or do they all somehow share that linked list?

Comment: One node of `AD (Album Database)` should have a linked list of `Tracks` in which songs of that particular Album are listed on the basis of `MBID (Music Database ID)`. MMD linked list have all the songs stored.